# How does Internet Explorer detect jre?

Tags: java, internet-explorer

There are multiple version of jre installed in the server machine. And for running applet on IE, I need jre 1.6 not jre 1.7, while latest jre 1.7 u 51 is installed in the system. Now I want to configure jre 1.6 with Internet Explorer without installing/uninstalling and component. What are the ways to apply settings? Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Control Panel` -> `Java`. Click on the `Java` tab, then click `View...`. From there you can enable or disable specific JREs which affects the version used by IE. You'll need to restart the browser after making the changes and clicking `OK`.